# SSH Tunnel / similar setup to connect to services which are associated to private network

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

here is my issue.

OS : Oracle Linux 7.8
Management IP(Putty accessible) eth0: 10.250.0.210
App IP (not accessible outside) eth1: 10.250.4.210

I have a website running on 10.250.4.210:80.

I need to access this site via 10.250.0.210 IP for testing purposes.
How can i accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.
UJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options

1. `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:80:10.250.4.210:80 user@10.250.0.210`

   This will forward any traffic sent to localhost:80 to 10.250.4.210:80 via 10.250.0.210
2. `ssh -D 127.0.0.1:8080 user@10.250.0.210`

   This will start a socks proxy on localhost:8080 which you can configure your browser to use, this will in turn will proxy all requests via 10.250.0.210

Putty has equivalent configuration options for both versions, but I believe Windows 10 ships with a version of the OpenSSH client these days so the command line version should work.

Comment: Worked like a charm. You are a saver @hardillb.